# Getting SQL session from application.yml for mybatis

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, mybatis

How can I get SQL session from application properties that I could use method

```
SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
```

In order to use MyBatis xml type queries.

I could only find examples of initializing sql driver either from xml or in class it self.

I got Application.yml :

```
spring:
  application:.name: test
  main.banner-mode: log
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [mybatis spring boot starter](http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/) then it already created an instance of `SqlSessionFactory` for you. Inject it into the spring bean where you want to use it:

```
 @Service
 public MySerice {
      @Autowired SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

      public void myMethod() {
           SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
      }
 }
```

If you don't have mybatis spring boot starter add it as a dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```